# ASP.NET Dynamically Set the Theme Name in ImageUrl Porperty

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i have used a image which i hardcoded it. but there is option of multitheme and i want to use it that if one person selects the blue theme then blue image should show and if the orange theme is chosen then orange image should show up..

This is the ASP.NET image code which i hardcoded

```
<asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/Images/listingnext.png" />
```

but i don't want it like that i want to show image on theme bases, like i said if its blue then blue image show and if orange or red then thier respective image should show..

i tried it like this.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default"+<%this.Theme%>+"/Images/listingnext.png" />
```

but its not working, how to make it possible?

Comment: maybe this will help `<%#this.Theme%>`. Are you sure your theme is Defaultblue, Defaultred etc.? If no, remove Default.

Comment: @Morpheus
no this gives issue.. here is its html out if i follow your way.
http://localhost:1589/App_Themes/%3C%25#this.Theme%25%3E/Images/listingnext.png

?? what to do?

Comment: what about `<%=this.Theme%>`

Comment: @Morpheus
Still the Same Problem, it adds extra encoding and dont work
"App_Themes/%3C%25=this.Theme%25%3E/Images"

Comment: `<asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%=ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/App_Themes/{0}/Images/listingnext.png", Page.Theme)) %>" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morpheus is right but instead of using following;

```
"<%=ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/App_Themes/{0}/Images/listingnext.png", Page.Theme)) %>"
```

Try this;

```
'<%# ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/App_Themes/{0}/Images/listingnext.png", Page.Theme)) %>'
```